# Any way to use Entity Framework Data Annotations in a xamarin.forms shared project?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xamarin.forms

I am using Entity Framework in my xamarin.forms android shared project. Is there a way I can use Entity Framework Data Annotations in my models? Simply adding the following using directive does not work (app loads then stops, with no reported errors):

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
```

Comment: I can't see to use Entity Framework on mobile solution as a good approach

Comment: What alternative would you suggest? I am already using EF for the web service that provides the data to my mobile app, so thought it might be a good idea to use the same framework on the mobile side.

Comment: Do you want connect your app with a database directly? If you have a web service existing the best approach would be to consume this web service.

Comment: I understand, and I've tried it long ago, but to use the heavy model of web / webservice just to "reuse" on mobile architeture was getting even worse, the code on mobile side got unnecessarily dirty, corrupted and bad smelling. I reccomend SQLite-net and SQLite-netExtensions

Comment: @Wilson - No, the app needs to work offline. The main thing I need is the ability to use LINQ queries against a local SQLite database.

Answer (score 1):

With the release of Entity Framework Core 2.0, you can now run EF with a SQLite database on iOS, Android and UWP.

First, your class library must be set to use [.NET Standard 2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core).

Install [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/) in every project, the traditional and the class library. It will install all other required dependencies, as appropriate. You are now ready to get coding. I have an example repo, [EFXamarin](https://github.com/adamped/EFXamarin/blob/master/EFXamarin/App.cs) on GitHub if you want to see a completed solution.

> **Note:** EFCore 1.0 with Mono 5.0+ will work on all platforms. EFCore 2.0 with Mono 5.0+ will work on all platforms except UWP . But only because support for .NET Standard 2.0 in UWP is still in the works, hence you must wait for that support, and then UWP will work with EFCore 2.0.